# What am I misunderstanding about calculating MTU?

Tags: tcp, ethernet, tcpip, gigabit-ethernet, mtu

Okay, I just finished resolving a jumbo frames issue between a few Xserves, a Netgear GSM7224, and a Drobo B800i. It turned out that the Xserves (Mac OS X 10.6.8 Server) and the Drobo B800i accept the MTU in bytes as normally expected (1500-9000), but the Netgear seems to have wanted it including the various ethernet headers/footers(trailers) and I ultimately ended up with the Xserves & Drobo configured with an MTU of 9000 and the Netgear ports set to an MTU of 9216.

I've used the following commands for testing & verifying the MTU between the two Xserves over the Netgear (Note: these are the Mac OS X commands, the Windows & Linux ones differ):

```
ping -D -s <mtu> <ip_address>

traceroute -F <ip_address> <mtu>
```

The former's usage is noted [in the `man` page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/10.6/man8/ping.8.html) as, "Specify the number of data bytes to be sent.  The default is 56, which translates into 64 ICMP data bytes when combined with the 8 bytes of ICMP header data." In testing, I found that to `ping -D 1472 <ip_address>` was the equivalent of MTU 1500 due to the 8 bytes of ICMP header data plus 20 bytes IP headers (see [this](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/222/~/what-is-the-jumbo-frame-supported-by-switches-and-adapters%3F) and [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-promise-and-peril-of-jumbo-frames.html)). That all makes sense.

Now, why is the equivalent command for a 9000 MTU `ping -D -s 8164 <ip_address>`? I've verified this is the limit before I star getting "sendto: Message too long" errors, but also that 9000 MTU is working correctly as `traceroute -F <ip_address> 9000` works and `traceroute -F <ip_address> 9001` does not. So, why 8164? I would've expected 8972 (MTU - 28 bytes, just like for 1500 MTU).

Also, why 9216 MTU for the Netgear? I counted 42 bytes for the MAC & ethernet headers (inc. CRC), plus 20 for IP headers (which should eat into the MTU).

I'm really rusty on this math and know I'm just missing something.

Comment: 9216 was almost certainly chosen because it's 9 x 2 ^ 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to the strange and mysterious world of jumbo frames! It's normal that jumbo frame ethernet gear has MTU > 1518 and < 65K  byte and you have to find a setting that is the lowest common denominator across your L2 domain to enable proper jumbo traffic.

My guess is that your ping/ICMP implementation only works for 8192 bytes payload, so 8164 + 28  (20 for the IP header and 8 for the ICMP header) gives you 8192 bytes.

MTU 9216 is also a standard 9K MTU on a lot of Cisco's gear, so my assumption is that Netgear wanted to be ''compatible'' to that.

Also note that MTU size specification should be taken seriously, a lot of vendors don't include 802.1Q (vLANs) or even L2 frame headers. Check with your switch vendor's documentation what they really specify when they're talking about MTU size.

Comment: Just a note to add: The MTU of your hosts and routers needs to match; the MTU of switches can be set to 12 bazillion for all it matters as long as it's above the hosts' settings (+header).